# Import Error in Python while Importing Request

Tags: python, fedora, python-import

I am new to python. I have my python file present in /home/prashant/Python directory i am trying to import request it is giving me error ImportError: No module named 'request'. 
    I am using Fedora 19. In my system there are two version of python /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages and /usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages. The request class is present in python2.7.

```
My $Pythonpath contains files of the directory i am in . 
I checked the sys.path 
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', '/usr/lib64/python33.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.3', '/usr/lib64/python3.3/plat-linux', '/usr/lib64/python3.3/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.3/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages']
```

I am not able to import anything from the python library. Please suggest something. I have been stuck with this for around 2 days.

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  Python 2.7 and Python 3.3 are totally separate.  Even if you installed a module to Python 2.7, you'll have to install it again with Python 3.3 to use it from Python 3.3.

Comment: I am not able to import any classes that are present in a different directory. That's my main problem. The class request is present in  Python 2.7 i am not able to import it from my current directory

Comment: Run `python -V` from the command line and check the version.

Comment: It shows Python 2.7.5

Comment: If I execute python filename.py it still says unable to find module request.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the problem. Thanks again i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your module is present in python2.7 you must be sure to use python2.7
for example if you use ipython there is 'ipython' (for python2.7) and 'ipython3'

you may also use the idle of python which is basically the same

Comment: My module is present in /home/prashant/Python this directory but i am not able to import /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages from this directory. I am new to both fedora and Python. I launched python from  /home/prashant/Python this directory contains some simple python programs .

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got the problem. Thanks again i really appreciate it.